# SQLite: How to JOIN with a partial column match?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, left-join

I'm trying to get all the data from the Documents table where the list of Box numbers in the BoxNumber table is somewhere within a string in a column in the Documents table.

The problem I'm running into right now is that none of the example code with `'%' + ColumnName + '%' or '%' || ColumnName || '%'` will work. it'll just return either nothing, or all the data in the Documents table.

**Example code:**

This returns all data in the Documents table instead of all data containing a document number similar to the list in the BoxNumbers table.

```
SELECT * 
from [Documents]
LEFT JOIN BoxNumbers ON 
BoxNumbers.BoxNum like '%' + Documents.DocNum + '%'
```

Anyone know why this isn't working? It seems like it's worked for people using MySQL and SQL server, so is this just another quirk of SQLite?

Comment: use join not left join  then you return only rows that match

Comment: This returned the same result. I ended up just pulling the data I needed from one column, putting it in a new column, and matching based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite concatenation operator is not `+` but `||`, so change to this:

```
SELECT * 
from [Documents]
INNER JOIN BoxNumbers ON 
BoxNumbers.BoxNum like '%' || Documents.DocNum || '%'
```

with `INNER` join.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too and it gives me the same result.